# Scheduling and thread quantum

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, cpu, scheduling

I was wondering can having too many threads potentially affect the time quantum that's given to a particular thread.

For instance, if my process have 100 threads, could the next/scheduled thread have a less quantum/burst than having 1000 threads since the scheduling would take some more time?

IMO, since scheduling runs it's own process, it has it's own thread to do the scheduling and so it shouldn't affect the other threads quantum (but should introduce some latency for the execution of the next/scheduled thread).

Any more ideas?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'one-to-many environment'.  None of the mainstream languages/libraries use anything but kernel-managed threads, so that would be one-to-one, for the simple reason that any other mechanism puts constraints upon code structure, (eg. 'you must not make any direct OS calls that might block), that most users don't want or cannot cope with.   Your Q.is unclear.

Comment: I'd like to say 'one-to-one' but I mistyped it. Now, I removed that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your operating system was designed from the ground up to be a [hard-real-time OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) (e.g. [Xenomai](https://xenomai.org) or [VxWorks](https://www.windriver.com/products/vxworks/)), you'll find that the OS's scheduler provides very, very few guarantees about when your threads will get to run, or how long they will get to continue running for when they do run.

Given the above, it's entirely likely that the presence of other threads on the same computer (whether they are threads inside your own process or threads in other processes) will affect the amount of CPU time that your own threads receive.  For example, if the other threads are running at a higher priority than your threads, and there is contention for CPU cores (i.e. more threads want to run at a particular time than there are CPU cores to run them on), then the scheduler will kick one of your running threads off its current CPU core before its quantum expires, so that the now-ready-to-run higher-priority thread can begin executing immediately.

In general, the answer to this sort of question is of the "there be dragons" variety -- which is to say, if you have written your multithreaded program correctly, then you shouldn't have to know (or care) what quantum-sizes your threads receive, as your code should be able to run correctly regardless of exactly how the scheduler hands out time slices to threads.

(The exception is when you [absolutely need real-time behavior](https://www.itbusiness.ca/news/nuclear-plant-powers-up-on-real-time-os/9084); in that case you probably want to be running on a real-time OS that can provide you with the guarantees you need)

As for how much time it takes the scheduler to determine which thread to start running, having more threads does increase the scheduler's overhead, but on most operating systems the increase is very marginal -- the scheduling algorithm is `O(log N)` or even `O(1)` with respect to number-of-threads.  You can still make the computer "hit the wall" if you keep adding more threads indefinitely, of course, but the limit you finally hit will more likely be related to RAM exhaustion than the performance of the scheduling algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! But I still don't quite get it if the scheduler kicks in on it's own thread (or process), or it "steals" some time of the currently running kernel thread.

Comment: I’ve never heard of a scheduler with its own thread or process.  Rather an interrupt goes off and the running user thread is briefly suspended while the interrupt routine runs a scheduler function that decides which thread to allow to run next.

Answer (score 0):

Using the confusing "one-to-many" terminology, what you are really dealing with is simulated threads. This is not an operating system implementation but rather a library implementation. The library will have no knowledge of quanta and the operating system will have no knowledge of the threads. Thus the thread have, as you suggest, zero impact on the quanta and process scheduling.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The reason I stated it is because, on some languages, you cannot create a kernel thread directly that may end up affecting pressure on the scheduler, right? Well, you can always create a process (or a light weight one) to maybe achieve what you want (pressure wise) on those languages but that's not my point. Either way,  the more threads your system have, the more time the scheduler spends to figure out which process/thread should be given a slot/burst to run. My question is can that scheduling "latency" affect this burst time in any way?